# Excel VBA Userform to Module/sub

Tags: excel, vba, userform

All,

I'm struggling with passing input variables from a userform to a module/sub. I've searched the form, but can't find a matching example.

E.g.

Form 1: Two input fields named **TextBoxA** and **TextBoxB** and 1 **Submit button.**
Module 1: some code in which I would like to use the input variables of TextBoxA and TextBoxB

Code in userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    pass = myuserform.TextBoxA
End Sub
```

Who can point me in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: If pass is the variable you want to access from a standard module, all you need is to declare pass as a public variable as "Public pass as String" on a standard module so that once you assign a value to the pass variable on userform, it can be accessed in any sub routine on a standard module

Comment: Examples here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/528707-pass-value-userform-textbox-vba-procedure.html

Answer (score 0):

Setup a Method which accepts two parameters in a Standard Module and pass the TextBox values as arguments:

```
Public Sub TestMethod(ByVal param1 As Variant, ByVal param2 As Variant)
    MsgBox "You passed: " & param1 & " and " & param2
End Sub
```

Then you only need to call the method in your button's Click event:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TestMethod myuserform.TextBoxA.Value, myuserform.TextBoxB.Value
End Sub
```